# Component Properties window - only three things can be seen rather than 20+

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis, business-intelligence

Trying to edit an SSIS package, when I go to the advanced editor on the update database package I can only see on the component properties page three properties. ID, Name and Description.

when my colleague opens this up he can see 20+ options including the SQL option I am needing to be able to edit.

Is this an issue with my SQL Business intelligence studio 2005? or an issue with access to the end database?

Many thanks,
Pierce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you don't have something installed quite right.  I'm betting you have Visual Studio installed, but not SQL Server development tools.  First thing I'd probably do is verify that Help, About shows the same app information on both yours and your colleague's boxes.

-

so versions look good, BIDS is installed.  Security?  Easiest way to check that out is to have your colleague log onto your box using their network id.  Not only will that check security, along they way, if there is something funky in your setup ( funky as in different from theirs not wrong ), your colleague is must more likely to spot it.  AFTER that works out ok, THEN I might hazzard uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio.  I don't believe I would mess with uninstalling and reinstalling anything .Net.

Comment: I have both Visual Studio and Development tools installed (as in I have BIDS as well). Checked from within visual studio and the version number is exactly the same for visual studio 2005. however the .NET version is slightly different, mine has SP2 at the end of it.

do you think its worth un-installing everything including .NET